# Displaying REST response on the VF page on button click

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, rest

Overview: I am making call to Pardto to fetch prospects and display them into Salesforce VF page on button click.

I am getting response fine from pardot but it is not displaying on the vf page. Not sure what's going wrong, not showing any error.

First, I would like to apologize as I am posting whole my code here. Not sure where I am doing wrong.

## REST Class:

```
public class callApi {
public List<Data> data;
public String Response;
public String apiKey;

//wrapper to display these fields on the vf page from response received
public class Data 
{
    public String FirstName {get;set;}
    public String LastName {get;set;}
    public String Company {get;set;}
    public String Score {get;set;}
    public String Grade {get;set;}
}

//Authenticating Pardot with Salesforce
public void Auth() {
        String email = 'XYZ@gmail.com';
        String password = 'XYZ';
        String userKey = '18f81f89c1d1a5c4a8997199886a4697';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint( 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/4' );
        req.setMethod( 'POST' );
        req.setBody( 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&user_key=' + userKey );

        HttpResponse res = new Http().send( req );

        String response = res.getBody();
        Integer startIdx = response.indexOf( '<api_key>' ) + 9;
        Integer endIdx = response.indexOf( '</api_key>' );
        String apiKey = response.substring( startIdx, endIdx );
        System.debug('******'+apiKey );
        getAndParse(apiKey);
        //return res;

}

//Getting and Parsing the response received from Pardot
public void getAndParse(String apiKey){

       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
       HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
       req.setEndpoint( 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/query?user_key=18f81f89c1d1a5c4a8997199886a4697&api_key=53bf05e2584221bcbaad133c8e831c45&output=bulk&format=json&created_after=2012-01-01T00:00:00&created_before=2018-09-10T00:00:00&sort_by=created_at&sort_order=ascending');
       req.setMethod( 'GET' );
       req.setBody( 'user_key=18f81f89c1d1a5c4a8997199886a4697'+'&api_key='+apiKey);
       req.setHeader('Accept','text/html');
       res = new Http().send( req );

      System.debug('***Response****'+res.getBody());
        this.response = res.getBody();
    System.debug('***Response****'+response);
        callApi temp = parse(this.response);    
    //    this.data = temp.data;
    //System.debug('***this.data****'+this.data);
    }

public List<Data> getData(){
    return this.data;
}

//deserializing the response received
public static callApi parse(String json) {
    return (callApi) System.JSON.deserialize(json, callApi.class);
}}
```

Response retrieved:

```
{"@attributes":{"stat":"ok","version":1},"result":{"prospect":[{"id":1704281,"campaign_id":969,"user_id":null,"salutation":"Ms","first_name":"test","last_name":"Akin","email":"kakin@athenahome.com","company":"Aethna Home Products123"}]}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="callApi">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Pardot Prospects Data">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons title="Prospects">
            <apex:commandButton value="Get Prospects" action="{!Auth}" reRender="myBlock" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection id="myBlock" columns="1">
            <apex:repeat value="{!data}" var="line">
                <apex:outputText value="{!line.FirstName}" id="theFNValue"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!line.LastName}" id="theLNValue"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!line.Company}" id="theCValue"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!line.Score}" id="theSValue"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!line.Grade}" id="theVGalue"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>
```

Comment: What did you find your debug statements?

Comment: Are you able to successfully deserialize the response? As far as I can see, your issue seems to be there. I don’t see the attributes as in the response mapped to the field names in your wrapper class.

Comment: I am getting the the debug as it is mentioned in "Response retrieved:"